# Cork underlayment for vinyl sheet?

Tags: flooring

Can i use cork as underlayment with a vinyl sheet? If not please let me know what i can use. I have tried to search up wether or not cork is okay with vinyl but it said both yes and no.

Comment: I think Vinyl needs to be on a hard floor, maybe cork might have too much give.  Ask the installer or supplier for recommendations.

Comment: What does the vinyl manufacturer say?